# Impossible to run ionic build android

Tags: android, cordova, build, ionic-framework

I have a couple of days with this problem, upgrade to the new version ionic and present the following problem:

```
BUILD FAILED

Total time: 11.556 secs

/Users/lixsys/app_view/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                throw e;
                      ^
Error code 1 for command: /Users/lixsys/app_view/platforms/android/gradlew with args: cdvBuildDebug,-b,/Users/lixsys/app_view/platforms/android/build.gradle,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: /Users/lixsys/app_view/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 1
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: /Users/lixsys/app_view/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 1
at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:131:23)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
at maybeClose (child_process.js:1008:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1080:5)
```

Previously in some cases I had also earned this problem but could solve the following ways:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/abdi/adt/sdk
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

And

```
brew install ant
```

But now nothing works, upgrade my JDK JAVA_HOME And ANDROID_HOME and check everything is correct. Crazy I have this problem I can not solve encounter multiple ways to fix it but no work for me. Also try removing the platform and add it again but nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you try to upgrade your android sdk to the latest version (API 22)?

I had same problems before that I can't run build command, but its works when I upgrade the sdk via android sdk manager.

or try to reinstall all of the prerequisites by following the instruction in this site : https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/09/install-android-cordova-ionic-framework-ubuntu/

Regards

Comment: Yes, I upgraded to the latest version of the SDK and still not working.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problems with the **android build** in my Windows 8.1 PC.

I installed Visual Studio 2015 and build successfully.

If you have windows, I suggest you to **create/build** your apps from Visual Studio and **edit** them in whatever editor you want.

Regards

Comment: Thanks for answering. I work on a mac. Then install and uninstall the android platform reaches that the problem was causing a plugin (ImageResizer for android) so remove the plug and run. Although strange error never ever shot.